# toString() changes the curly braces into square?

Tags: java, json, hashmap, tostring

I have the following construct in my code for the following JSON

```
SomeVariable = 
   {  
       "FirstVar":{  
          "service1":"value1"

       }
}
```

For this I have the following
 code in Java

```
        Map<String,String> internal_service_var = new HashMap<String,String>();
        internal_service_endpoint.put("service1","value1");

        Map<String, String> first_var = new HashMap<String,String>();
        first_var.put("FirstVar", internal_service_var.entrySet().toString());

        Map<String, String> some_var = new HashMap<String, String>();
        some_var.put("SomeVariable", first_var.entrySet().toString());
```

Here is how I try to use it in the JSON to send over wire
Note that the value of the property in the JSON needs to be a String

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject
json.put("var", some_var);
```

This sets the 'var' property in the json to be

```
[SomeVariable = [  "FirstVar":[  "service1":"value1"]]]
```

Instead of

```
SomeVariable = {  "FirstVar":{  "service1":"value1"}}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I get this result `{"var":{"SomeVariable":"[FirstVar=[service1=value1]]"}}`, not either of the variations you've presented.

Comment: It's also unclear why you are storing the `toString` result of the `entrySet`.

Comment: can you use `Map<String, Object>` ? this can avoid your `toString()`

Comment: The `toString()` of HashMap does not return the data in JSON format. If you want JSON objects use only `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toString() of HashMap does not return the data in JSON format. If you want JSON objects use only JSONObject.

Alternatively, use xstream:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
String jsonRepresentation = map.toXML();
```

jsonRepresentation will have your json. Yes, for reasons only known to ancient sages, xstream uses toXML for serialization. It's misnamed, and unlikely to change to anything else.